# how to host a website that have website content in AWS and domain in godaddy account?

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting, godaddy-api

I stored website content in AWS EC2 Cloud and I purchased domain from godaddy. Any one please explain how to do DNS settings in godaddy/AWS to live my website.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below case
 - GCM registration should be done upon user login and GCM unregister should happen when user logout from application
 - In your case may be application is doing GCM registration when app opened and unregister happening when app is closed or minimized

Comment: So What should I do ? for making it dynamic/automatic. user got frustrated as the are not getting notification on time. Any suggestion to make it automatic and should go notification like whatsapp.

Comment: Install app in two different device.  Keep app open in one device and minimized on other device. Now send test push and check both device are receiving push. If any of them does not receive then above mentioned case is applicable.